# I'm trying to parse all the urls of the tabs I have open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to copy the url's of all the open tabs with javascript and then put the urls into a html textarea, however it's not working.
This is my code.

```
            chrome.windows.getCurrent({"populate":true}, function(currentWindow) {
               var tabURLs = [];
               var tabs = currentWindow.tabs;
               for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) {
                   tabURLs.push(tabs[i].url);
               }
               var textArea = document.getElementById("thing");
               var text = textArea.value;
               tabURLs.forEach(item => text += item);
            });
        };
```

Keep in mind this is a google chrome extension, let me know how I can fix this!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: `text += item` - `text` is a string. This (`+=`) does not update the content of the element you got that string from.

Comment: Yeah I know, my apologies, it's my second time posting. Also, there is no error, I'm not really sure what else to add. @Andreas also, don't really get the point of downvoting my post if there is NOTHING to add? Just seems kinda dumb?

Comment: @Andreas What would the code be, then? I'm not too experienced with chrome extensions, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you so much, it works! Feel free to enter it as a new reply so I can mark it as the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is modifying a copy of the element's value, not the element itself.
You need to replace `text +=` with `textArea.value +=`

P.S. The code can be shortened:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({}, tabs => {
  document.getElementById("thing").value = tabs.map(t => t.url).join('\n');
});
```